# My ssis package is running very slowly

Tags: ssis, msbi

My ssis package is running very slowly. The package is like this, using FTP task we will collect files from server and then loads that data into sql server table. It is scheduled to run every night as a job. When I run it in IDE it is very fast. And when run it on SQL server Aegnt as a job, for some days it fast. But as days progress the package is taking much time to execute. What I have to do for upcoming this issue?  Please give me in detail.

Comment: Your question lacks sufficient detail to be resolved. It runs fast on your machine, slow on the server. Are you using the exact same source and destination? Where is the package spending its time? Is it in the FTP step or the "load into sql tables" step. What specifically are you doing in the "load to sql step?" What data types are you dealing with? What does your target table(s) look like? Are there triggers on these tables? What about concurrent activity in the destination?

Comment: Obviously without profiling the package nobody will give you the remedy. It is going to be a walk in a dark forest. On pre SSIS 2012 you can install https://ssisreportingpack.codeplex.com/ and all the newer SSIS implementations come with the canned performance reports http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213362.aspx that will help you pinpoint the exact issue and then ultimately solve it.

Comment: what are the controls you are using like lookup, oledb command, aggregate like that.. more details needed. Check which task taking more time in BIDS progress window.

Answer (score 0):

Logging implementation makes sense. Than you can find out certain part(-s) of your ETL, which slows down entire package.

As for some variants:

1. What about other tasks on SQL or FTP servers the same time as
   package execution? Looks like other scheduled tasks (backups,
   defrags etc.) take server resources from time to time. Is there any
   repeated sequence of performance decreasing?
2. Amount of processed data. Let's say files
   represent sales, which have drastically other amount on weekend.
3. Based on code. For example, manual execution let
   server to truncate some temporary tables, but automatic version uses
   the same tables w/o truncation, which slows down every next day.

But first of all: logging may help as a start point of fixing.